# how to validate JSON string before converting to XML in C#

Tags: c#, xml, json

1. I will receive an response in the form of JSON string.
2. We have an existing tool developed in C# which will take input in XML format.
3. Hence i am converting the JSON string obtained from server using Newtonsoft.JSON to XML string and passing to the tool.

**Problem:** 
When converting JSON response to XML, I am getting an error

> "Failed to process request. Reason: The ' ' character, hexadecimal
>   value 0x20, cannot be included in a name."

The above error indicates that the JSON Key contains a **space** [For Example: \"POI Items\":[{\"lat\":{\"value\":\"00\"}] which cannot be converted to XML element.

Is there any approach to identify spaces only JSON key's ["POI Items"] and remove the spaces in it?

Also suggest any alternative solution so that we needn't change the existing solution?

Regards,
Sudhir

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/) and replace the names while loading the json..

```
JsonSerializer ser = new JsonSerializer();
var jObj = ser.Deserialize(new JReader(new StringReader(json))) as JObject;

var newJson = jObj.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None);
```

.

```
public class JReader : Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader
{
    public JReader(TextReader r) : base(r)
    {
    }

    public override bool Read()
    {
        bool b = base.Read();
        if (base.CurrentState == State.Property && ((string)base.Value).Contains(' '))
        {
            base.SetToken(JsonToken.PropertyName,((string)base.Value).Replace(" ", "_"));
        }
        return b;
    }
}
```

**Input :**  `{"POI Items":[{"lat":{"value":"00","ab cd":"de fg"}}]}`

**Output:** `{"POI_Items":[{"lat":{"value":"00","ab_cd":"de fg"}}]}`

Comment: Shouldnt the cd":"de fg" be converted to cd":"de_fg" as well?

Comment: @GeorgeNikolaides No, as asked in question `Is there any approach to identify spaces only JSON key's ["POI Items"] and remove the spaces in it?`

Answer (score -2):

I recommend using some sort of `Regex.Replace()`.
Search the input string for something like:

```
\"([a-zA-Z0-9]+) ([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\":
```

and then replace something like (mind the missing space):

```
\"(1)(2)\":
```

The 1st pair of parenthesis contain the first word in a variable name, the 2nd pair of parenthesis means the 2nd word. The `:` guarantees that this operation will be done in variable names only (not in string data). the JSON variable names are inside a pair of `\"`s.

Maybe it's not 100% correct but you can start searching by this.
For details check MSDN, and some Regex examples
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx